# How to access request body in scala play via asText if header is missing content type

Tags: scala, content-type

An incoming request in my play application does not have the content-type headers attribute set. This makes accessing the body via

```
request.body.asText
```

problematic, as it seems the automatic parsing only provides the body via

```
request.body.asRaw
```

How can I handle the missing content-type attribute, to still be able to access the body (assuming it is parse able) via ".asText"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tolerantText body parser will ignore the content type headers:

```
object MyController extends Controller {

  def action = Action(parse.tolerantText) { req => 
    val text = req.body
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! Is there a variant which would allow to have the Action still handle a Request[AnyContent] but at some point get the request.body.asRaw as parsed as text?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe you could use the parser manually by feeding it the data from asRaw inside of your controller.

Comment: I just realized that a text body can be read as a string via  `new String(request.body.asRaw.get)` Not bullet prove though but its a start.